# Samsung Galaxy Core GT-i8262 dual sim problem

Tags: dual-sim

I am using a *Samsung Galaxy Core Duos* (GT-i8262). When I bought it, I was able to use both SIM cards. But after some time I was having problem that only SIM 1 works, other SIM always says "no network card". First the OS was Android 4.1 but now I ave rooted it to SaMyKat V3, Android 4.4.2 – and 2nd SIM is not working.

[image: Both Sims are Inserted.]
<sup>Both SIMs are Inserted. (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: Might be a problem with custom ROM. Have you read the known issues of SamyKat?